# opening specific area in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
    var ge;

    google.load("earth", "1");

    function init() {
    google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCallback, failureCallback);

    addSampleButton('Create a Circle!', buttonClick);

    }

    function initCallback(instance) {
    ge = instance;
    ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

    // add a navigation control
    ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);

    // add some layers
    ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, true);
    ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_ROADS, true);

    var la = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
    la.setRange(50000);
    ge.getView().setAbstractView(la);

    createCirclePolygon();

    document.getElementById('installed-plugin-version').innerHTML =
     ge.getPluginVersion().toString();
    }

    function failureCallback(errorCode) {
    }

function createCirclePolygon() {
  function makeCircle(radius, x, y) {
    var center = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
    var ring = ge.createLinearRing('');
    var steps = 100;
    var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
      var lat = 30 + x + radius * Math.cos(i / steps * pi2);
      var lng = -85 + y + radius * Math.sin(i / steps * pi2);
      ring.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(lat, lng, 0);
    }
    return ring;
  }

  var polygonPlacemark = ge.createPlacemark('');
  polygonPlacemark.setGeometry(ge.createPolygon(''));
  var outer = ge.createLinearRing('');
  polygonPlacemark.getGeometry().setOuterBoundary(makeCircle(0.1, 0, 0));
  ge.getFeatures().appendChild(polygonPlacemark);
}

function buttonClick() {
  createCirclePolygon();
}
```

Hi,i'm using Google play ground to build some code to create circle polygon,i'm able to draw the circle,i just want to redirect the map where i'm drawing circle polygon but it is redirecting to some other place(default place),how can i change this one using my code,any help highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try use fitBounds() to redirect the map to where have something drawn

```
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    bounds.extend(marker.position);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Works fine for markers

Comment: Thanks for you'r reply,i did it in some other way,it's working now

Comment: You must tell us how to fix the problem, if you found the solution

Comment: var lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);

// Set new latitude and longitude values.
lookAt.setLatitude(30);
lookAt.setLongitude(-85);
  lookAt.setRange(50000.0);

// Update the view in Google Earth.
ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);                                        sorry i thought about it but totally forgot to post the solution,Thanks